# Does Scala have guards?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I started learning scala a few days ago and when learning it, I am comparing it with other [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) languages like ([Haskell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_%28programming_language%29), [Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_%28programming_language%29)) which I had some familiarity with. Does Scala has [guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_%28computer_science%29) sequences available?

I went through pattern matching in Scala, but is there any concept equivalent to guards with `otherwise` and all?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Yes, it uses the keyword `if`. From the [Case Classes](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/107) section of A Tour of Scala, near the bottom:

```
def isIdentityFun(term: Term): Boolean = term match {
  case Fun(x, Var(y)) if x == y => true
  case _ => false
}
```

(This isn't mentioned on the [Pattern Matching](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/120) page, maybe because the Tour is such a quick overview.)

---

In Haskell, `otherwise` is actually just a variable bound to `True`. So it doesn't add any power to the concept of pattern matching. You can get it just by repeating your initial pattern without the guard:

```
// if this is your guarded match
  case Fun(x, Var(y)) if x == y => true
// and this is your 'otherwise' match
  case Fun(x, Var(y)) if true => false
// you could just write this:
  case Fun(x, Var(y)) => false
```

Answer (score 20):

Yes, there are pattern guards. They're used like this:

```
def boundedInt(min:Int, max: Int): Int => Int = {
  case n if n>max => max
  case n if n<min => min
  case n => n
}
```

Note that instead of an `otherwise`-clause, you simply specifiy the pattern without a guard.

Comment: What will be the `n` in this case and please give an working example for the above.

Comment: @Jet `n` will be the argument given to the function. [Here](http://ideone.com/HhSuF0)'s an example of using the function.

Answer (score 9):

The simple answer is no. It is not exactly what you are looking for (an exact match for Haskell syntax). You would use Scala's "match" statement with a guard, and supply a wild card, like:

```
num match {
    case 0 => "Zero"
    case n if n > -1 =>"Positive number"
    case _ => "Negative number"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled to this post looking how to apply guards to matches with multiple arguments, it is not really intuitive, so I am adding an random example here.

```
def func(x: Int, y: Int): String = (x, y) match {
  case (_, 0) | (0, _)  => "Zero"
  case (x, _) if x > -1 => "Positive number"
  case (_, y) if y <  0 => "Negative number"
  case (_, _) => "Could not classify"
}

println(func(10,-1))
println(func(-10,1))
println(func(-10,0))
```