# Scala Pattern Matching with tuple

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm working on the first assignment of the Coursera class.

For the following code, I'm stuck on the compile-time errors.

```
    object pascal {
        def main(c: Int, r: Int) = {
                pascal(c, r)
            }
            def pascal(c: Int, r: Int) = {
                (c, r) match {
                    case ((r < 0) || (c < 0)) => throw new Exception
                                                 ("r and c must be > 0")
                    case r == 0 => 1
                    case r == 1 => 1
                    case c == 0 => 1
                    case r == c => 1
                    case _ => pascal(r-1,c-1) + pascal(r-1,c-1)
            }
        }
     }

vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/Workspace/Scala/hw1$ scalac pascal.scala
pascal.scala:7: error: not found: value ||
                        case ((r < 0) || (c < 0)) => throw ...
                                      ^
pascal.scala:8: error: value == is not a case class constructor, nor 
does it have an unapply/unapplySeq method
                        case r == 0 => 1
```

Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is invalid syntax in scala: you need to use so called *[guards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266915/does-scala-have-guards)* to check for boolean properties:

```
def pascal(c: Int, r: Int) = {
   (c, r) match {
     case (c,r) if ((r < 0) || (c < 0)) => throw new Exception
                                                 ("r and c must be > 0")
     ...
}
```

By the way much more idiomatic to write code like this:

```
def pascal(c: Int, r: Int) = {
   require((r >= 0) && (c >= 0), "r and c must be >= 0")
   (c, r) match {
     case (_, 1) => 1
     ...
}
```

And you have to change error message to "r and c must be >= 0"

Comment: Not sure if the assignment explicitly requires working with pattern matching, but isn't this code packing c and r (which are already separate parameters) into a tuple just to unpack them again in the case? I would have used just a simple if

Comment: Your last piece of code is wrong: `case r == 0` won't compile

Comment: How can I do: case "where c == r"?

Comment: @Kevin try `(c,r) match { case(\`c\`,\`c\`) => ... }` -- this instructs pattern matching to do a comparison by value

Comment: Thanks. Once I compile using "scalac Pascal.scala," how can I even run this program?

Comment: @Kevin http://www.scala-lang.org/node/166 and please, [ask a different question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if it is unrelated to this one

Comment: Is using the tick ` to force comparison by value hacky?