# Avoid repeating the same variable in a chain of conditions

Tags: raku

I have a script with a conditional and a pile of checks using the same variable. Something similar to this:

```
my $size = "123B";
say "OK" if $size ~~ Str && $size.ends-with("B") && $size.chop >= 0;
```

Would it be possible to rewrite the line in a way that would avoid the repetition of `$size`? I thought something like junctions which I have no idea how to apply to that. Or maybe something else, but shorter to my line.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about:

```perl
my $size1 = "123B";
given $size1 {
      say "OK" if .Str && $_.ends-with("B") && $_.chop >= 0;
};
```

`$_` is the 'Topic Variable' in Raku (and Perl as well). You can abbreviate to `$_.ends-with()`, or shorten the code even further to `.ends-with()`, as shown below. Similarly `$_.chop` can be shortened further to `.chop`, as shown below.

---

Or using the `[&&]` reduction meta-operator:

```perl
my $size2 = "123B";
given $size2 {
      say "OK" if  [&&] .Str, .ends-with("B"), .chop >= 0;
};
```

Or with an `all()` junction:

```perl
my $size3 = "123B";
given $size3 {
      say "OK" if  $_ ~~ all(.Str, .ends-with("B"), .chop >= 0);
}
```

Or eliminate the `given` block entirely:

```perl
my $size4 = "123B";
say "OK" if  $size4 ~~ all(.Str, .ends-with("B"), .chop >= 0);
```

https://course.raku.org/essentials/loops/topic/

Comment: I know, but in that case you are just changing the variable. I'm trying to avoid repeating of the same variable in each condition. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @BrassP. The `$_` can be omitted in the condition parts. Just write `.ends-with("B")` and `.chop >= 0`, for instance. That's the magic of the `$_` variable.

Comment: Thanks!. I love the metaoperator idea: `say "OK" if $size ~~ [&&] .Str, .ends-with("B"), .chop >= 0`

Comment: @jubilatious1 I like your last suggestion best -- but only if it's fixed. :) It doesn't gracefully handle `$size` not working as a string, doesn't complain if it's just `'B'` (it says that that's `OK`, which feels wrong), it will throw an exception (`Cannot convert string to number`) with, eg, `'AB'`, and may display warnings (eg if `$size` is declared as `my Str $size;` but not initialized). This code fixes all those things, and drops the `.Str` because my `try` tweak of your suggestion means it doesn't matter: `say "OK" if quietly try $size4 ~~ all .chars > 1, .chop >= 0, .ends-with("B")`.

Comment: `.Str` does not represent `$size ~~ Str`, does it? shouldn't it be `.isa(Str)`?

Comment: @MustafaAydın that's an excellent suggestion! Let me check around with a Raku-guru or two. I'll keep you updated.

Answer (score 4):

I've fallen into the habit of creating a `subset` when dealing with some things like this. Mainly because I find it nice to be able to re-use it in further `~~`'s and to be able provide descriptive names for potentially complex logic:

Here's what I would do:

```
subset MyDescriptiveSubset where { all .Str, .ends-with("B"), .chop >= 0 }

say "OK" if $size ~~ MyDescriptiveSubset
```

Answer (score 3):

`{ when /B$/ { say 'OK' } } given my Str $size = '123B'`

my answer is a bit cheeky since you know that $size is a Str if it matches the regex and you know if it has a B as the last char, then .chop >= 0

```
my $size = '123B';
{ when (Str && /B$/ && .chop >= 0) { say 'OK' } } given $size
```

this generalization is probably more in the spirit of what you asked

^^^ my first answer vvv corrections per comments

Here is my improved answer.

```
my $size = '123B'
{ when ( Str, /B$/, .chop >= 0 ).all { say 'OK' } } given $size;
```

Also my initial pass misunderstood the idea that the 123 of 123B was to be interpreted as a number ... I thought the idea of the .chop >= 0 part was to check the number of bytes in the string.

The biggest advance was to define a test ;-) like this:

```
my @test = '123B', '-12B', '123A', '123AB', 1234;
{ when ( Str, /B$/, .chop >= 0 ).all { say 'OK' } } for @test;
```

The individual tweaks were:

- reinsert .chop >= 0
- use an All Junction to distribute the when tests and not && ... thus avoiding the when ( TypeObject && .. ) trap

Thanks to the commenters I have learned a few things today!

Comment: Technically, this fails for negative values of `$size` (I know...negative Bytes are unlikely, but anyway). I can get the second example to correctly reject negative `$size` by changing `Str` to `.Str`. Not sure about how to correct the first example (guessing because the regex cannot detect negative numbers).

Comment: The second code solution won't work. Try changing the `$size` declaration to any string, eg the null string or `'aaa'`. It'll keep displaying `OK`. The problem is `TypeObject && ...`. A type object is `False` so it shortcircuits the `&&` expression, yielding the type object. Next, `when TypeObject { say 'OK' }` displays `OK` if `TypeObject` smartmatches the current topic. And that's true if the type object is `Str` and the given topic is a string -- any string. See [an answer of mine to an earlier SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49835992/1077672) for some discussion of this.

Comment: @raiph I'm wondering if the second code example is cured by `given $size { when ( .chars.so && /B$/ && .chop >= 0) { say 'OK' } };`. This properly handles negative values as well as empty strings. What it doesn't handle gracefully is a $-sigiled variable that's not a string but a Blob (an error will be thrown). But maybe the OP's okay with that?

Comment: "and you know if it has a B as the last char, then .chop >= 0." That ain't cheeky it's cheating! The code `.chop >= 0` isn't counting the number of characters but instead coerces the chopped string to a number and compares that with zero. So it'll fail (actually throw an error) for, say, `'AB'`, or `'123AB'`, or `'A123B'`. Granted, the original code skips many checks too, but it does include `.chop >= 0` and the challenge was to do *better*!  I've added a comment to @jubilatious1's answer addressing the various weaknesses I've seen in all suggestions so far.

Comment: @jubilatious1 Your suggestion has other problems too. So do the solutions in your answer. I'll suggest something in a comment on your answer which fixes all the ones I see. Also, I'd just not bother with `when`. I don't see upsides to using it for this problem and I do see downsides (even if the error I pointed out was fixed). (That said, I immediately started trying solutions using `when` as soon as I read the Q. The `$size ~~ Str` code instantly led my mind in that direction. But then I remembered the `Str &&` problem and eventually realized `when` just didn't buy me what I was looking for.)

Comment: @raiph Either `Str && 0` or `Str && 1` are problematic because they're not acting on `$_`. It needs to be written `.Str && 0` or `.Str && 1`.

Comment: @jubilatious1 They're worse than problematic *regardless of what they're acting on*. First, any type object boolean coerces to `False`. So `TypeObject && ...`, no matter what the `...` is, will always return `False`. Second, this is so even though they *are* always acting on `$_` in a smart match, such as a `when`, which was the context for my comment. And in addition to realizing `when` was the wrong tool (imo), I also realized that if you add a `try` to protect against a range of possible problems, such as input like `'123.B'`, then the `.Str` is *redundant*. cf my comment on your answer.

Comment: @raiph we're going to have to agree to disagree then. In the REPL `'cat'.Str.so`
 returns `True`, and `1.Str.so` returns `True`, and `0.Str.so` returns `True`, but empty-string `''.Str.so` returns `False`.

Comment: @jubiliatious1 We don't *have* to disagree. :) Of course `.Str` works as you showed (if `$_` is set). My point was that characterizing `Str && 0` or `Str && 1` as "problematic" dramatically understates the problem. They are *always utterly useless*. So I disagreed with *the reason you gave for them being "problematic"* or, as I just put it, *utterly useless*. It's nothing to do with `$_`. In the code `when Str && 0 { ...}` or `when Str && 1 { ...}`, the `Str && ...` bit is *still* utterly useless, and *always would be*, and this is so even though they *are* being smartmatched against `$_`.

Comment: @librasteve  _"...I thought the idea of the `.chop >= 0` part was to check the number of bytes in the string."_ I still believe that to be true, and I hope you do as well!

Comment: nope - ```'128B'.chop``` will give you ```Str|128``` then ```>=``` is a numeric compatison so that will coerce it to ```Int|128``` so then you you can have eg. ```'-128B'.chop >= -129; #True```

Comment: Which is what you want, correct? `'-128B'.chop >= 0; #False` rejects any negative bytes, so you don't have to write a Regex. Which is what I think OP (@BrassP) was going for.

Comment: @jubilatious1 Nope. The `.chop` bit returns a *string*. The `>= 0` coerces that string to the *number* it parses from the string. (Not "the number of *bytes* in the string", but just what the number is parsed as.) For example, `10` coerces to the number *ten*, not *two*.

Comment: @raiph the point is to do a numeric comparison, which will recognize negative numbers without the user having to write a `<[+-]>?` signed Regex. I mistakenly said 'bytes' but no-doubt an experienced Raku programmer could write the `Int` <-->  `bytes` conversion?

Comment: @jubilatious1 "the point is to do a numeric comparison, which will recognize negative numbers without the user having to write a `<[+-]>?` signed Regex." I don't see anyone here suggesting use of a regex for that. (Just for catching the last `B`, which we seem to agree is better done with `.ends-with`.) In the meantime `.chop >= 0` will automatically use Raku's built in number parsing, including a sign, and the simplest way by far that I know of to eliminate non-numbers is to use `try .chop >= 0` or similar. See my comment on your excellent answer for a more general `try` defense against bugs.